# Why is lambda better in this code snippet?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm reading about lambda's on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

In **Approach 1** they mention

> "You would have to rewrite a lot of your API to accommodate this
>   change. In addition, this approach is unnecessarily restrictive; what
>   if you wanted to print members younger than a certain age, for
>   example"

```
public static void printPersonsOlderThan(List<Person> roster, int age) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (p.getAge() >= age) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}
```

In **Approach 5** they use lambda expression:

```
printPersons(
    roster,
    (Person p) -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
        && p.getAge() >= 18
        && p.getAge() <= 25
);
```

However, even in this lambda expression, we have to modify the API when we want to modify the search criteria.

Why is using a lambda here better compared to using a custom method in the first approach?

Comment: If your question is regarding code, the code in question needs to be posted here directly, as text.

Comment: "Even in this lambda expression, we've to modify the API when we've to modify the search criteria." What? Why? If I want to use a different criterion, I use a different lambda expression. The function remains the same.

Comment: I don't see how Approach 5 requires modifying the API.

Comment: This has nothing to do with lambda... Approach 5 has a functional interface parameter, which contains the checks to test a condition. You could specify this without a lambda, just implementing the interface, and passing an instance of the implementing class. A lambda is just an "eye candy" to the programmer, to make code more readable, more simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with small examples is that they sometimes hide the real benefits. In this case they are looking at a method that contains reporting logic. Approach 1 looks like this:

```
public static void printPersonsOlderThan(List<Person> roster, int age) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (p.getAge() >= age) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, if you need other reporting, such as

- persons younger than a certain age
- persons between specific ages
- persons of a specific gender
- etc

You will have to write a new method for each use case, where you re-implement the for-loop and printing instructions:

```
for (Person p : roster) {
    if ( specificCondition) {
        p.printPerson();
    }
}
```

What you really want is to *re-use* all the logic around that condition and *only* re-write the specific search condition for your use case, without re-writing looping logic and print logic.

In approach 5, the `printPersons` method takes a lambda as parameter.

```
printPersons(
    roster,
    (Person p) -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
        && p.getAge() >= 18
        && p.getAge() <= 25
);
```

You can pass whatever search query to the `printPersons` method, without having to write new methods like `printMalePersonsOlderThanAndYoungerThan` where you have to re-write the full for-loop and all the printing instructions.

At the specific moment the `printPersons` is written, the `Person` `getGender()` method might even not yet exist, so it would have been impossible to deliver a `printMalePersonsOlderThanAndYoungerThan` a priori. So another advantage of approach 5 is that you can provide methods that are future proof and if your model changes, you will not have to write any more additional code than the specific condition.